# Android - Lockdown All Other Apps

Tags: java, android, kiosk, kiosk-mode, lockdown

I'm currently creating an app that requires you to specify an amount of time to lockdown into that app. Basically, it disables all other functions (notifications, home, back, long presses, etc) for the amount of time the user specified. I believe this is called Kiosk mode.

Is it possible to do such thing using the Android SDK? If so, how can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance,
~ Pkmmte Xeleon

Comment: Android is being used by many companies, including mine, for various industrial and instrument purposes, and the lack of support for kiosk mode is a huge problem.  I spoke with Romain Guy at AnDevConIII who said they had received many requests for this and Google was hoping some third-party would develop a commercial ROM for this purpose but as of that time there was none.  I wish Google/Android would recognize this is an important market segment and support it natively.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. unfortunately SDK will not provide much help, so you have to go with manual tweaking. A service in background will have been killing all the running processes except your app. you can disable home key. i can not remember exact method name, so search for it. for back disabling override keyDown()/ onBackPress().